# java не удается активировать потоки http-nio в Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, https

У меня есть приложение - клиент и приложение - сервер. Я передаю post запросы на сервер в количестве 30 шт. Сервер использует spring-boot с такими параметрами:

```
-Dserver.port=3333 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-threads=30 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-connections=30 
-Dserver.tomcat.max-post-size=-1 
-Dserver.tomcat.accept-count=100
```

У меня создается 30 соединений в сервере. Для обработки запросов как я понял используется пул http-nio. Это можно увидеть в visualvm:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При установлении такого параметра: max-threads=30 создается 30 потоков http-nio.

При этом когда клиент отправляет 30 запросов в профайлере видно, что не все nio активны, и даже если я отправлю 100 или 150 запросов, то будет видно, что только часть nio активны, а другие просто простаивают.

При наблюдении я видел, что потоки меняются, но все равно есть 5-7 потоков, которые простаивают.

Подскажите как активизировать потоки? Чтобы они всегда были включены в работу и не простаивали? Даже если отправить 100 запросов, и при это изменить на 100 соединений, то не все потоки nio активны. Подскажите, любые идеи будут полезны.